# Column matching

Tags: linux, scripting

I have two file , the format as below .

## file A

```
Name   Education Level  Sex
====   ===============  === 
Mary   Unviersity        F
Peter  Unviersity        M
John   Unviersity        M
Eva    High School       F
Bill   Post Graduate     M
Eddie  Post Graduate     M
```

## file B

```
Education Level Type 
=============== ====
Unviersity       A
High School      B
Post Graduate    C
```

I would like to do the matching , add the third column to the matched file , the matching result would be as below file , would advise how to do it ? thanks

## Output file after match

```
Name   Education Level  Type    Sex 
====   ===============  ====    === 
Mary   Unviersity       A       F   
Peter  Unviersity       A       M
John   Unviersity       A       M
Eva    High School      B       F
Bill   Post Graduate    C       M
Eddie  Post Graduate    C       M
```

Answer (score 0):

First, some pre-processing. Remove headers (the first two lines in both files). Then, make tab as the field separator. Sort A on the second field and B on the first field. Lets say this leads to files "a" and "b". Then, the join command can be used.

```
$ cat a
Eva High School F
Bill    Post Graduate   M
Eddie   Post Graduate   M
John    Unviersity  M
Mary    Unviersity  F
Peter   Unviersity  M
$ cat b
High School B
Post Graduate   C
Unviersity  A
$ join -12 -21 -t$'\t' a b 
High School Eva F   B
Post Graduate   Bill    M   C
Post Graduate   Eddie   M   C
Unviersity  John    M   A
Unviersity  Mary    F   A
Unviersity  Peter   M   A
```

You can run the final output through awk to get the required format.

Comment: sorry to ask how to use the method , I just tried run "join -12 -21 -t$'\t' a b" , but nothing output , would advise is there anything that I should do ? thanks

Comment: Have you converted File A into "a" and B into "b" as per pre-processing steps mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Please post your final post-processed "a" and "b" files and the output of the join command.

Comment: may be I am not understand your method , what I have done is rename my file to "a" and "b" , the file content is not changed .